# Enabling HTTP Compression in WebSphere Application Server 7

Tags: gzip, websphere, compression, was7

I know the correct way of enabling gzip HTTP Compression for a WebSphere Application Server is to activate and configure the mod_gzip module in the IBM HTTP Server connected/installed in this environment.

However, our WAS 7 environments don't have the IBM HTTP Server. Can we still use gzip HTTP Compression by enabling it directly in WAS 7? If that is possible, how can we accomplish it?

---

Edit:

After talking to some colleagues and some further research, there seems to be a way to enable HTTP Compression directly in the configuration file (XML) of the HTTP connector embedded in WebSphere. Nevertheless, we haven't been able to find the exact file so far. Can anyone validate this information? In a positive case, does anyone know which file we should be looking for?

Comment: You should look into putting a proper HTTP server in front of WAS7 and using the WAS plug-in, even if running it on the same host as the WAS7 instance.  WAS7's HTTP connector is just... lacking.

Comment: I definetely agree on that. However, this is not an option, as of now. Our team can, at most, recommend they attach an instance of IBM HTTP Server to our WAS7 environment, as it would allow us to solve the problem the right way. Unfortunately, we have to provide at least a temporary workaround (unless there isn't one) even though it is not the best practice.

Comment: @Doug i think your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without a third-party servlet filter -- the only settings in WAS in this neighborhood that show up misleadingly in searches are related to very specific jax-ws webservices responses.